# connecting database on android[offline]

Tags: android, database, unity-game-engine

Can someone tell me how to connect offline database from android?

I have some script here..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.SqliteClient;

public class dbAccess : MonoBehaviour {
private string connection;
private IDbConnection dbcon;
private IDbCommand dbcmd;
private IDataReader reader;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

public void OpenDB(string p)
{
connection = "URI=file:" + p;
dbcon = new SqliteConnection(connection);
dbcon.Open();
}

public void CloseDB()
{
reader.Close();
reader = null;
dbcmd.Dispose();
dbcmd = null;
dbcon.Close();
dbcon = null;
}

IDataReader BasicQuery(string query)
{
dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
dbcmd.CommandText = query;
reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
return reader;
}

int CreateTable(string name, string[] col, string[] colType)
{
string query;
query = "CREATE TABLE" + name + "(" + col[0] + " " + colType[0];
for(var i=1; i<col.Length; i++){
query += "," + col[i] + " " + colType[i]; 
}
query += ")";
try{
dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
dbcmd.CommandText = query;
reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch(Exception e){
Debug.Log(e);
return 0;
}
return 1;
}

int InsertIntoSingle(string tableName, string colName, string value)
{
string query;
query = "INSERT INTO" + tableName + "(" + colName + ")" + "VALUES (" + value + ")";
try{
dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
dbcmd.CommandText = query;
reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch(Exception e){
Debug.Log(e);
return 0;
}
return 1;
}

int InsertIntoSpecific(string tableName, string[] col,string[] values)
{
string query;
query = "INSERT INTO" + tableName + "(" + col[0];
for(int i=1; i<col.Length; i++){
query += "," + col[i];
}
query += ") VALUES (" + values[0];
for(int i=1; i<values.Length; i++){
query += "," + values[i];
}
query += ")";
try{
dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
dbcmd.CommandText = query;
reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch(Exception e){
Debug.Log(e);
return 0;
}
return 1;
}

int InsertInto(string tableName, string[] values)
{
string query;
query = "INSERT INTO" + tableName + "VALUES(" + values[0];
for(int i=1; i<values.Length; i++){
query += ")" + values[i];
}
query += ")";
try{
dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
dbcmd.CommandText = query;
reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch(Exception e){
Debug.Log(e);
return 0;
}
return 1;
}

public string[] SingleSelectWhere(string tableName, string itemToSelect, string wCol, string wPar, string wValue)
{
string query;
query = "SELECT" + itemToSelect + "FROM" + tableName + "WHERE" + wCol + wPar + wValue;
dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
dbcmd.CommandText = query;
reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
string[] readArray = new string[reader.RecordsAffected];
int i=0;
while(reader.Read()){
readArray[i] = reader.GetString(0);
i++;
}
return readArray;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

and i have database in my unity asset that called **user.db**

the problem is, how to save username when i tap **OK** button..

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include a database in a Unity android project it initially gets packaged in the APK and you have to extract it out of the APK in order to access it.

The first thing you should do is place it in the streaming assets folder and then you can call this code as a Coroutine to extract it to you androids persistent data path

```
void Start()
{    
    //Only run on first run
    if(!PlayerPrefs.GetInt("first_run").Equals(1))
    {
        string _databaseFileName = "user.db";
        string _databasePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + _databaseFilename;
        StartCoroutine( ExtractFileFromJar(_databaseFilename, _databasePath));
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("first_run", 1);
    }
}

public static IEnumerator ExtractFileFromJar(string dbName, string writePath)
{       
    WWW loadDB = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + dbName);
    yield return loadDB;
    File.WriteAllBytes(writePath, loadDB.bytes);
}
```

From there you can access the database from your persistent datapath. I use SQLiteKit to run queries against it.

http://u3d.as/content/orange-tree/sqlite-kit/3ka

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example on where you can call the function. I usually call it as soon as the program opens. But make sure you only call it once or your overwrite it everytime the program opens.

Comment: i have some following error when i try to insert that code..
here's the error..


Assets/dbAccess.cs(21,37): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString(string, string)' has some invalid arguments


Assets/dbAccess.cs(21,37): error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `int' expression to type `string'


Assets/dbAccess.cs(29,17): error CS0103: The name `File' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Im sorry, I had a typo in my code, I fixed it in the example above. Playerprefs should have been setting an Int, and I had it set a string by mistake.

Comment: why I still got some error? it's said "Assets/dbAccess.cs(29,17): error CS0103: The name `File' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: you need to add "using System.IO" at the top of the script

Comment: I want to build into APK, why its still got some error?
it said the mysql.data.dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found..

Comment: I dont think that dll is supported, that is why I suggested SQLiteKit